# A question on subcritical percolation

Tags: percolation

Consider some 2D lattice of infinite extent where each site can either be $0$ or $1$ with probability $p$. It is known there exists some critical probability $p_c$ below which clusters of $1$ values are finite, and above which clusters may be infinite.

Usually, the books derive results for the cluster size $s$ when $p\approx p_c$ so there are generally large cluster sizes. In this case, the cluster size distribution generally has the form
$$ p(s) = s^{-\tau}e^{-s/s_\xi}, $$
where $\tau$ depends on the lattice in question and $s_\xi$ is a cutoff length that depends on $1/(p-p_c)$, so it diverges at the critical probability.

However, I am unable to find any literature on the opposite extreme: what is the distribution of cluster sizes like when $p\ll p_c$? Anecdotally I found it's exponential in some math papers, although I haven't found any physics literature exploring this point. Any guidance is appreciated !